# I am learning python, Getting this error "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" how to solve this error

Tags: python-3.x

```py
data = obj.generateSession(USER_NAME,PWD)
refreshToken= data['data']['refreshToken']

# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I am learning python and am getting this error "`'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`". How to solve this error?

Comment: It is because a variable is `None`. Most probably `data`.

Comment: What are the contents of `data`? What about `data['data']`?

Comment: data=obj.generateSession(USER_NAME,PWD)

Answer (score 0):

Check `data = obj.generateSession(USER_NAME,PWD)`, most probably it's receiving a NoneType value therefore not subscriptable when looking for further info in `refreshToken= data['data']['refreshToken']`

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have tried to subscript NoneType object. Data object or `data['data']` object must have None type.
Try to solve this by

```
print(type(data))
print(type(data['data']))
```

One of that must be `None`.

Or using debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is either with the data or data['data']. In order to be sure, run :

```
data == None
```

if this returns True, the Nonetype issue is with the data object.

```
data['data'] == None
```

if this returns True, then the Nonetype issue is with the data['data'] object.

Happy Coding!